# novato en c# y en general

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¿Que tal? me acabo de registrar en este estupendo foro, y queria saludar y pedir ideas sobre la creacion de un programa de gestion de casas rurales en c#.
Cree la base de datos en MySql(nada del otro mundo), me preguntaba si al realizar una aplicacion con windows forms y realizar un menuStrip, ¿Es mejor que cada item sea un form o como estaria bien implementado?
Estoy abierto a ideas o ejemplos un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si puedes poner algo de tu código, creo que te ayudaría a obtener una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Disculpen, no se mucho español, pero seria probablemente mejor si tu primero hace classes para todo; solo despues hace forms.

Comment: Son demasiados clases para poner aqui, simplemente tengo una aplicacion de las plantillas de Windows Forms, un MenuStrip del cuadro de herramientas de Visual Studio y nose si es mejor hacer que cada item del menu sea un nuevo form para manejar los dataGridView o con la propiedad visible o algo asi. Ya digo que soy bastante novato.

Comment: Como menciona lo ideal es pasar el modelo de la base de datos a Clases de C#, en cuestion de gustos me agrada mas WPF aunque WF tiene mas tiempo y por ende hay mas cosas y mas recursos cuando uno se atora. Lo ideal como menciono es crear las clases, esto en un proyecto de Libreria de Clases ya sea el normal o el Portable. Ya que si en un futuro deseas hacerla App o lanzar un API a tu sistema no tengas que volver a rescribir las clases.

Comment: Se podria aplicar un modelo database first en aplicaciones WF?

Comment: cuando dices database first quieres decir que usas entity framework ? el modelo de persistencia no deberia afectar al diseño de la UI

Comment: Hola Rubiopixi, lamentablemente tu pregunta no tiene una respuesta objetiva, y las respuestas se basarán en opiniones, lo mas probable es que la pregunta sea cerrada. Por favor te recomiendo que leas esto: [¿Que tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depende del diseño de la aplicacion, pero lo comun es que un item de menu abra una nueva ventana.
Esto podrias implementarlo en un diseño `MDI`, en donde las ventanas abren dentro de un form definido como container.

[Introduction to MDI Forms with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C)

Entonces los items de menu abres ventanas contenidas en este form.

Sino quieres usar MDI podrias usar un form de base con un `Panel` y abrir `user control` dentro.
En este caso el item del menu creara una instancia del `user control` que agrega como control dentro del `Panel`

```
public void menustripAltaProducto_Click(..){

     ucAltaProducto uc = new ucAltaProducto();
     Panel1.Controls.Add(uc);
}
```

De esta forma no abres ventanas modales sino que usas `User Control` como form

Uan variante a esto seria usar `TabControl`, en donde en cada tab abres un user control con la funcionalidad de la pantalla

[How to: Add and Remove Tabs with the Windows Forms TabControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb7xae05(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public void menustrip1_Click(..){

     TabPage tab = new TabPage("Alta Producto");

     ucAltaProducto uc = new ucAltaProducto();
     tab.Controls.Add(uc);

     tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias voy a informarme sobre el diseño MDI, a ver que tal y si no me convence ya pruebo otras cosas un saludo y gracias